# Deducing return type of std::vector::back()

Tags: c++, stl, return, rvalue, lvalue

I know the title is a bit ambiguous but esentially, I was wondering if we were to make a wrapper class for some STL container (i.e vector or list), what would be the correct way to return some of the methods that return references to an element. Consider following code:

```
template<typename T>
class wrapper{

private:
std:vector<T> v;

public:
T back() const {
return v.back();
}

};
```

As per my understanding, `back()` method would return a const lvalue reference to the last object in a `vector`, so what happens if we return that by a copy, will we get a copy of a reference or of an object?  And is this something that compiler can optimise as a part of return value optimisation?

Comment: wrapper::back() returns a rvalue. You will get a copy of last element in v vector.

Answer (score 2):

To preserve reference types use `decltype(auto)`:

```
decltype(auto) back() const {
    return v.back();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> what would be the correct way to return some of the methods that return references to an element.

The correct way depends on your needs i.e., whether you need a copy or an lvalue reference / const lvalue reference. Personally I would recommend returning a const reference or a reference.

> `vector::back()` method would return a const lvalue reference to the last object in a vector

It returns a reference / const reference. If your `vector` is `const`, it returns a const reference, otherwise it returns a reference. See: [`std::vector<T, Allocator>::back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/back)

> so what happens if we return that by a copy, will we get a copy of a reference or of an object

Just a copy will be created of the referenced object.

> And is this something that compiler can optimise as a part of return value optimisation?

<strike>Yes, From cppreference on [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision):</strike>

It depends on your the type `T` and the compiler is not *required* to do it. From cppreference on [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision):

> Under the following circumstances, the compilers are permitted, but not required to omit the copy and move (since C++11) construction of class objects even if the copy/move (since C++11) constructor and the destructor have observable side-effects. The objects are constructed directly into the storage where they would otherwise be copied/moved to. This is an optimization: even when it takes place and the copy/move (since C++11) constructor is not called, it still must be present and accessible (as if no optimization happened at all), otherwise the program is ill-formed:
>
> - In the initialization of an object, when the source object is a nameless temporary and is of the same class type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the target object. When the nameless temporary is the operand of a return statement, this variant of copy elision is known as RVO, "return value optimization".

Also, if you return by copy, the copy constructor of `T` may throw and you may have an invalid object.

Comment: The last part about copy elision is not clear to me. The operand in the `return` statement in the question is lvalue, not prvalue. It would apply if we had something like `return T{};`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. My mistake. I will update the answer, copy elision can happen here, but it is not mandatory.

Comment: Copy elision can't happen here. `back()` returns a reference, from which we then create a copy and return it. To avoid a copy, we must return a reference in the wrapper. (Although before C++17, an _additional_ copy could be created, which could be elided. But let's talk modern C++)

Answer (score 0):

In a `const` member function of the `wrapper` class in the question, the vector `v` is `const`. It's `back()` member function returns `std::vector<T>::const_reference`. If the vector was not `const` the return type would be `std::vector<T>::reference`.

In this case those two types are equivalent to `const T&` and `T&`, but a proper wrapper for `vector` could also allow for the allocator that the vector uses, and the return type might not be so simple. With `template <class T, class Alloc> wrapper { ... std::vector<T, Alloc> v; ... }` the allocator `Alloc` can provide its own reference type; to match those types, the correct names come from the typedefs inside `std::vector`.

Comment: back() does not return an iterator. it does return a reference to T. I dont understand the second part.
The perfect return-type-deduction would be decltype(auto) (as another answer stated).

Comment: @phön — whoops, silly typo. That should have been `reference`. Fixed.